# Is there any method in Wordpress to check whether the content is generated for XMLRPC call like for Feeds

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I have a plugin which echoes something before the content on webpage. Normally I don't want it on feeds so I do this

```
if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_feed() )
  echo $script;
```

Now, when some one uses xmlrpc calls to get the posts, there is nothing I could check against to prevent my script geting echoed into the post. Is there any thing like is_xmlrpc() to check this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but you could create it yourself pretty easily (and I really suggest to wrap that into a function because the detection is not overly stable and you might need to change it):

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
function is_xmlrpc() {
    return defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') && XMLRPC_REQUEST;
}
```

This works because in [`xmlrpc.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/xmlrpc.php) at the very top that `XMLRPC_REQUEST` constant is being defined.